# Browser not able to parse manifest.json in Node.js application after deploying it to Cloud foundry

Tags: node.js, manifest, cloud-foundry

I have created a Node.js application with angularJS. I need to add 'Add to Homescreen' functionality to the application. So I have added the manifest.json as below.

`{
    "name": "TEST-APP",
    "short_name": "TEST-APP",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "background_color": "#313131",
    "theme_color": "#313131",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "images/Test-App.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/Test-App.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "http://localhost:6001/",
    "display": "standalone"
}`

While testing the application in localhost, it able to parse the manifest. But after deploying it to Cloud Foundry, i am getting the below error.
[image]
Please help me with this.

i have tried Changing the manifest.json encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: can you share a link to deployed app?

Comment: I cannot share the link. It is a production application.

Answer (score 0):

There really shouldn't be that much of a difference from running locally vs running on CF. Here's some things you can check though...

- Look at the output of staging (i.e. the nodejs buildpack). Make sure it's installing the same version of Nodejs & packages that you're using locally. The buildpack tends to default to the newest/latest versions of things. If you're using an older version locally, you may see differences.
- Look at the actual `manifest.json` file that is being served up from the app when running on CF. It is possible that it's not serving up what you expect and thus JSON cannot be parsed. For example, accessing the JSON could return a 404 or a server error. These would not be valid JSON and thus would fail. If you switch to the Network tab, you can see if there were issues & you can see the exact response data returned.
- You can install the `cf local` plugin. This allows you to run your app using the same buildpack that runs it on CF, but in a local Docker container. It allows you to validate the "runs locally fine" theory while using the exact same versions of software that will run your app on CF.

  https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cflocal

Hope that helps!